# Setting focus and highlight in a textarea field

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I'm displaying a `textarea` input via PHP using the command :

```
print " '<textarea rows='16' cols='30'>$flist'</textarea><BR>";
```

I would like the `textarea` to have focus and contents `$flist` be selected automatically. All I've found to date is how to select when the input is clicked.

How would I accomplish this using javascript (no jquery)?

Thanks,
Walt

Answer (score 0):

Write your code as below:-

```
// Assign a id to textarea and rewrite below line :-
print "<textarea rows='16' cols='30'>$flist</textarea><BR>";
```

In Js use [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp):-

```
<script>
function setFocusToTextBox(){
   document.getElementById("mytext").focus();
}
</script>
```

Comment: How would I call this function? What I did below works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];
textarea.focus();
textarea.select();
```

if you have more then one textarea on a page you will need to add id to textarea:

```
print "<textarea id='text' rows='16' cols='30'>$flist</textarea><BR>";
```

and use getElementById:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `focus()` and `select()` :

```
document.querySelector('textarea').focus();
document.querySelector('textarea').select();
```

Your PHP code should be :

```
print "<textarea rows='16' cols='30'>$flist</textarea><BR>";
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').focus();
document.querySelector('textarea').select();
```

```html
<textarea id='text' rows='16' cols='30'>text here</textarea><BR>
```

Answer (score 0):

So here's what actually worked...

```
print " <textarea id='txarea' rows='16' cols='30'>$flist</textarea><BR>";
print "     <script>\n";
print "        document.getElementById('txarea').focus();\n";
print "        document.getElementById('txarea').select();\n";
print "     </script>\n";
```

It ended up being a combination of the responses. 
Thanks to all for the clues...